# I want to return some key and value in the Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, orm, relational-database, laravel-query-builder

I have two Models (Store, Product) and Relationship hasMany

```
public function products(){
   return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

And I want to return response collection, in class StoresCollection extends ResourceCollection

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->collection->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'id' => $item->id,
                'seller_id' => $item->seller_id,
                'store_product' =>  $item->products()->get(),
            ];
        });
    }
```

But I don’t want to return every key in the "store_product", I just need "id" and  "is_featured" only, and I don’t want them all.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": [],
    "code": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "seller_id": 6,
            "store_product": [
                {
                    "id": 1017,
                    "seller_id": 89,
                    "is_featured": 0,
                    "is_category_featured": 0,
                    "is_approved": 1,
                    "created_at": "2020-4-21T00:00:00.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-4-21T00:00:00.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "seller_id": 6,
            "store_product": [
                {
                    "id": 1018,
                    "seller_id": 89,
                    "is_featured": 0,
                    "is_category_featured": 0,
                    "is_approved": 1,
                    "created_at": "2020-4-21T00:00:00.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-4-21T00:00:00.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
    "paging": {
        "total": 2,
        "per_page": 15,
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "to": 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to request only some columns by `get()` method, in your case like:

```
'store_product' =>  $item->products()->get(['id', 'is_featured']),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Resource for store_product e.g `StoreProductResource` and define the keys in the toArray() method.

Then come back and modify StoreCollection::toArray() like this:

```
 return $this->collection->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'id' => $item->id,
                'seller_id' => $item->seller_id,

                'store_product' =>  StoreProductResource::collection($item->products()->get()),
            ];
        });
```

I also believe the callback map is unnecessary in your use case. toArray() just needs to return an array. Laravel handles the mapping. Except there's some logic you're doing in the callback which isn't included in the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your keys that you want to return in relationship as well:

```
public function products(){
   return $this->hasMany(Product::class)->select(['store_id','id', 'is_featured']);
}
```

**Note:** Remember to add the columns assigned to the foreign key matching both tables. For instance, in my example, I assumed a `Store` has a `Product`, meaning that the columns assigned to the foreign key would be something like `store.id = product.store_id`, so I had to add `store_id` to the list of selected columns;

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to implement this one

```
'store_product' =>  $item->products()->value('id', 'is_featured'),
```